# Image not Rendering in html on append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am getting a response from an API like so (This is a part of it)

```
{
    "Content": "<span class="PubAPIAd"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ru.gwallet.com/r1/ad/MTAuMTAyLjIuNzQgODg4OA==/c366792T246999B22980F24848R13t2?data=zmxnsak48w9msqkeq9hbz4dja7u4sstqxoircsqutictr7inboxhwujhu8n1c9scn5t53xs396h6re6nz4u1a1brbnmzzxjt7qy8difcdkgk9g34ngknd9qky7w5udgzrhm64h74abbpyh47djbgb5acp3f1ghb1kfeysy716j133gqhydk3au6ydj8h14aztefkrjfp7fj3mqj54sntbrhosseh397g7g7ns75ja3rhwcq9gzao5m6g8h9zph5sckzeoahibtru5cbda7bpcfmrra&auction_price=0.05"></script></span>  <img src="http://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId=51762&siteId=51766&adId=95947&adServerId=243&kefact=0.050000&kaxefact=0.050000&kadNetFrequecy=1&kadwidth=320&kadheight=50&kadsizeid=31&kltstamp=1416004675&indirectAdId=0&adServerOptimizerId=2&ranreq=0.05247270006223126&kpbmtpfact=0.050000&dcId=2&tldId=80779&passback=0&imprId=139A6406-07A0-4DD1-8B76-81C35E5EA412&mobflag=1&ismobileapp=1&modelid=604&osid=7&udidtype=0&campaignId=6575&creativeId=0&pctr=0.000000&wDSPByrId=11&imprCap=1&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fatt_1617ee24-7ff6-4402-9e8b-77dcb53f880f.com" width="1" height="1" />" 
}
```

I am trying to append the "content" to a div on my web page using Jquery append or js innerHTML to display an ad. However i do not see an image.

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = response.Content;
```

But if i hard code this into my HTML to start with it displays an image.

Would really like to know why this is happening and how i can fix it

Note: I have no control over the backend. Also this image is an ad i am trying to load so please disable ad blocker to try viewing it.

EDIT: This is what is see in the console

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId…mprCap=1&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fatt_1617ee24-7ff6-4402-9e8b-77dcb53f880f.com".
```

EDIT 2 : Here is an example of it Hard Coded (where it renders properly). Need to disable ad blocker to view  --> http://jsfiddle.net/0z1cybrf/

Comment: The value of content doesn't seem to be a valid string, as the double quotes in the tag attributes terminates the string early. Do you see the content generated by the appended script? Do you see any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: @vijar When I visit `http://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId=51762&siteId=51766&adId=95947&adServerId=243&kefact=0.050000&kaxefact=0.050000& ... [URL_CUT] ... Fatt_1617ee24-7ff6-4402-9e8b-77dcb53f880f.com`, I get a blank page.  How are you hardcoding it?  are you just putting in this url into the `src` attribute in your `img` tag?

Comment: @Raffi No i am putting the entire "Content" into a div in my html file.

Comment: @vijar I've noticed at the end of the `img` tag there is a `height` and `width` attribute and their both set to `1`.  Unless your using css to change the height and width I would change those values.

Comment: @Raffi Here is an example of it hardcoded. Also the height and width are for a tracking pixel and no the ad . You can find my example here --> http://jsfiddle.net/0z1cybrf/

Comment: @vijar No image is showing up for me, I just see `Ads Response Test`.  Maybe it is a `MIME type` problem with the server after all?

Comment: @Raffi Make sure your ad blocker is disabled since this is an AD. LEt me know if you still cant view it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `response.Content` returns `html` that you want to insert into `myDiv`.  In this case you can simply use jQuery.

```
$('#myDiv').append(response.Content);
```

also as **Samuel Liew** pointed out in the comments, your string isn't valid.  You can fix this by changing the quotes next to the attributes to `'` (single quotes).

**EDIT - Try this:**

```
$('#myDiv').append('<span class="PubAPIAd"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ru.gwallet.com/r1/ad/MTAuMTAyLjIuNzQgODg4OA==/c366792T246999B22980F24848R13t2?data=yydr8ogr3e5zsn1cacgexhma83oaf1xzjfyna3mgdwi473hf3wjcwujhu8n1c9scn5t53xs396h6re6nz4u1a1brbnmzzxjt7qy8difcdkgk9g34ngknd9qky7w5udgzrhm64h74abbpyh47djbgb5acp3f1ghb1kfeysy716j133gqhydksc3h869rc47kzse66wx4hpx4uiqj54sntbrhosseh397g7g7ns75ja3rhwcq9gzao5m6g8h9zph5sckzeoahibtru5cbda7bpcfmrra&auction_price=0.05"></script></span><img src="http://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId=51762&siteId=51766&adId=95947&adServerId=243&kefact=0.050000&kaxefact=0.050000&kadNetFrequecy=1&kadwidth=320&kadheight=50&kadsizeid=31&kltstamp=1416004779&indirectAdId=0&adServerOptimizerId=2&ranreq=0.20811005185761733&kpbmtpfact=0.050000&dcId=2&tldId=0&passback=0&imprId=E1FB9573-FF52-4CAC-BFE1-92EDBDC23FD2&mobflag=1&ismobileapp=1&modelid=604&osid=7&udidtype=0&campaignId=6575&creativeId=0&pctr=0.000000&wDSPByrId=11&imprCap=1&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fatt_1617ee24-7ff6-4402-9e8b-77dcb53f880f.com" width="1" height="1" />');
```

Tell me if you get the same result.

**### Final Edit ###**

It seems the javascript in the `script` tag isn't executing and that's why the image isn't showing up.  To prove this you can insert the `Content` like you were doing before, and then visit the link given in the `<script>` `src` attribute. Copy the script and go to your console.  Paste the code into the console and press enter.  The image should show up.  At least it did for me. You can try hardcoding the `script` tag into your html, because that wont change.

**HTML code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="functions.js></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ru.gwallet.com/r1/ad/MTAuMTAyLjIuNzQgODg4OA==/c366792T246999B22980F24848R13t2?data=yydr8ogr3e5zsn1cacgexhma83oaf1xzjfyna3mgdwi473hf3wjcwujhu8n1c9scn5t53xs396h6re6nz4u1a1brbnmzzxjt7qy8difcdkgk9g34ngknd9qky7w5udgzrhm64h74abbpyh47djbgb5acp3f1ghb1kfeysy716j133gqhydksc3h869rc47kzse66wx4hpx4uiqj54sntbrhosseh397g7g7ns75ja3rhwcq9gzao5m6g8h9zph5sckzeoahibtru5cbda7bpcfmrra&auction_price=0.05'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <DIV id="myDiv" ></DIV>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery Code `functions.js`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#myDiv').append("<img src='http://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId=51762&siteId=51766&adId=95947&adServerId=243&kefact=0.050000&kaxefact=0.050000&kadNetFrequecy=1&kadwidth=320&kadheight=50&kadsizeid=31&kltstamp=1416004779&indirectAdId=0&adServerOptimizerId=2&ranreq=0.20811005185761733&kpbmtpfact=0.050000&dcId=2&tldId=0&passback=0&imprId=E1FB9573-FF52-4CAC-BFE1-92EDBDC23FD2&mobflag=1&ismobileapp=1&modelid=604&osid=7&udidtype=0&campaignId=6575&creativeId=0&pctr=0.000000&wDSPByrId=11&imprCap=1&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fatt_1617ee24-7ff6-4402-9e8b-77dcb53f880f.com' width='1' height='1' />");
    });
});
```

Comment: It is exactly the same what he is trying but using jQuery, it no solved the issue

Comment: @ianaya89 Not entirely.  The `innerHTML` isn't the equivalent to `.append()`.  It's more like `.html()`.

Comment: I have tried it with both and the result is the same

Comment: @Raffi Not always, first the result is the same. The behaviour of append will be different from innerHTML if the param if an element but in this case the response.Content is a string so the behaviour will be the same.

Comment: @vijar Can you tell me if your getting any errors in your console?  It could be simply because of a broken link.

Comment: @Raffi This is what i am getting . Also i mentioned if i hard code this into my html it renders fine        This is what the console says :     Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://aktrack.pubmatic.com/AdServer/AdDisplayTrackerServlet?operId=1&pubId…mprCap=1&pageURL=http%3A%2F%2Fatt_1617ee24-7ff6-4402-9e8b-77dcb53f880f.com".

Comment: @ianaya89 It's only the same at first if he has nothing in his `myDiv`.  If he does, it will be erased.  In the question he said append, and thats why I went that route.

Comment: @Raffi I get your point, I mean that is the same for this particular problem becauase the issues is not related with that.

Comment: It's weird that it works fine if its hard coded.  That means the server is giving the correct MIME type, try looking through the `src` of the image.  It could be that some characters are encoded weird.

Comment: @Raffi Tried your edit and it was an invlaid string. I escaped the string and tried again and the result is the same as i was getting before(same message in console)

Comment: @Raffi Thanks a lot . Happy we were able to get ot the bottom of this. However since this is an ads api i cannot be certain it will be the same script. Is there some code i can add to execute the script after appending?

Comment: @vijar you can try isolating the script path and then running this: `$.getScript("pathToScript.js", function(){});`  This will load it up for you and then execute it.